# How to read xml value with Powershell

Tags: powershell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo>
  <Tier Path="\\10.10.44.61\Case Study\" />
  <Force Path="\\10.10.44.61\Orto Study" Atomic="False" />
</Foo>
```

How can I read in powershell `Tier Path` value?
I am expecting to get the value of `\\10.10.44.61\Case Study\`

Comment: Assuming your xml is in a variable named $xml: `$xml.Foo.Tier.Path`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo>
  <Tier Path="\\10.10.44.61\Case Study\" />
  <Force Path="\\10.10.44.61\Orto Study" Atomic="False" />
</Foo>'

([xml]$xml).Foo.Tier.Path
```

As long as you are using an `xml` type (which I do by casting) you can reference the path directly as members of the object.